# How do I search a particular directory with tracker-search-tool

Tags: files, search, directory, tracker

I have directories like ~Work ~School ~Movies.
Is it possible to search for files in only one of those directories with tracker-search-tool (or with tracker in general)?

Comment: Hm, seems this is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/30020/advanced-searching-in-tracker-search-tool-filter-by-folders - but that one did not really get answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked in IRC and it is not possible with tracker-search-tool but it is possible on the CLI:

> The tracker search tool is pretty simple (and I am not very familiar
>   with it) but at the least this can be
>   done using command line tools (or
>   custom queries in general).  For instance, to find all
>   the images under a specific directory
>   (or actually the url of which starts
>   with that specific directory) that
>   Full-Text-Search match the string
>   testi can be obtained with

```
tracker-sparql -q "SELECT ?uri nfo:fileName(?uri) WHERE {?uri a nfo:Image . ?uri fts:match 'testi' . ?uri nie:url ?url FILTER(fn:starts-with(?url, 'file:///home/masi/Pictures/Wallpapers')) }"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tracker Search](https://github.com/wooni005/tracker_search) is a frontend for tracker that allows filtering the search results by file path. However, the paths must be entered in the configuration file `~/.config/tracker_search/settings.conf` before starting the program. Each path entered will appear in the GUI as a checkbox.